# Spring Data - no transaction is in progress

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm trying to configure a custom Spring Data Repository to replace some funcionality of spring.

Everything works fine in `@Repository` interfaces, but in the `@Repository` implementations, I got **no transaction**.

Error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Here is my Configuration File:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan ({"com.app.core.authentication", "com.app.core.service","com.app.core.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.app.core.repository"})
public class AppCoreConfiguration implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()  {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/postgresDS");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.app.core.entity");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return txManager;
}


@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

@Bean
public EntityManager entityManger () {
    return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager();
}
```

}

And my repository class:

```
@Repository
public class ClientRepository extends JPABaseRepository<String, Client> implements IClientRepository {

@Autowired
public ClienteRepository (EntityManager em) {
    super(Cliente.class, em);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Cliente save(Client client) {
    return saveAndFlush(client);
}
}
```

And the interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IClientRepository extends IJPABaseRepository<String, Client> {
    ...
}
```

Did someone know why this custom `@Repository` class didn't get the transaction manager?
This is strange, because all interfaces not implemented works fine...

I already tried to put `@Transaction`'s annotation everywhere... including change from  RESOURCE_LOCAL to JTA and so on...

Comment: Make sure you aren't duplicating bean instances also a thing wrong with your configuration is that you have an `EntityManager` bean in your configuration, don't do that as this will create a non-spring managed `EntityManager` instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've double checked for beans duplications... everything is ok. About the `EntityManager`, i need to inject in the Repository constructor... the only way to do that is specifying the `EntityManager` as `@Bean`. Is there any way to do that without create a explicit `EntityManager`? Thanks!

Comment: I would consider this a design flaw. The `EntityManager` isn't thread-safe and should be recreated on for each thread. Normally spring handles this for you (it creates a transaction/thread-safe proxy for the `EntityManager` which utilizes Spring Transaction support). Your instance doesn't.

Comment: Alright... I didn't knew that. I'll take a look on alternative custom spring data repositories that fix this issue. Thanks a lot for your contribution!

Comment: The class `JPABaseRepository` isn't from Spring Data, at least I don't know that class so it must be something custom from your library. In general you should have a factory that instantiates your custom classes and this will take care of the `EntityManager`.

Comment: The `JPABaseRepository` extends the SimpleJpaRepository and add some custom methods. But like you said I see in the spring docs that I will need to create this factory.

Comment: This is my JpaBaseRepository by the way: https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/ff5fdd95fc39f4272b65

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks a lot for your insight! I just removed the entitymanager and create a factory to add default behavior to all repositories. It is working fine now. If you want to put an anwser, I'll be happy to mark as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using custom JPA Repositories which extend Spring Data JPA you need a factory to create instances of those repositories. As mentioned in the Spring Data JPA [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

The problem with your current approach is the fact that you are creating a, non-spring-managed, instance of an `EntityManager`.

```
@Bean
public EntityManager entityManger () {
    return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}
```

Normally Spring creates a [transaction aware proxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) for the `EntityManager` but in your case (due to the `@Bean` method) your custom implementation gets a plain `EntityManager`. Creating a factory (as mentioned above) will solve this.